# Saving coordinates into mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save lat, long into mongodb with Node.js and mongoose. The mongodb coordinates should looks like this in the end:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("57faa6b5a005aa179276d25d"),
      "loc" : { "coordinates" : [ 40.730610, -73.935242 ], "type" : "Point" }}
```

**Node.js saving into mongodb but this is not working for me**

```
   router.post('/setData',function(req,res){

     exp = test();
     exp.loc = {"loc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.730610, -73.935242]}};
     });

     exp.save(function(err,doc){
       console.log("done");

     });
```

**MongoDB- after saved into MongoDB**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57faa6b5a005aa179276d25d"),"loc" : { "_id" :     ObjectId("57faa6b5a005aa179276d25e"), "coordinates" : [ 0, 0 ], "type" : "Point" }}
```

**Schema**

```
var geoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: 'Point',
      default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      default: [0, 0]
    }
});
```

How can I save the data that the mongodb property looks like so. The id is generated automatically:

```
       { "_id" : ObjectId("57faa6b5a005aa179276d25d"),
      "loc" : { "coordinates" : [ 40.730610, -73.935242 ], "type" : "Point" }}
```

Comment: what is exp? If you are using an schema reference, objectId, you have to give the id of the location and not the full object itself. ```var loc_id = loc.save()``` and then ```exp.loc = loc_id ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect

```
exp.loc = {"loc":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.730610, -73.935242]}};
```

Must be

```
exp.loc = {"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.730610, -73.935242]};
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing `loc` in your schema:

```
var geoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  loc: {
    type: Object,
    properties: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: 'Point',
        default: 'Point'
      },
      coordinates: {
        type: [Number],
        default: [0, 0]
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: 1)saving error: WriteError({"code":16755,"index":0,"errmsg":"Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('57facb076d24291d0606ea43'), loc: { loc: { coordinates: [ 40.73061, -73.935242 ], type: \"Point\" },    2) unknown GeoJSON type: unknown GeoJSON type: { _id: ObjectId('57faca8286d63d1cf508fb67'), loc: { coordinates: [ 40.730610, -73.935242 ]